# SDK Components NOT installed

Tags: android, sdk, components

"The following SDK components were not installed: sys-img-x86-addon-google_apis-google-22 and addon-google_apis-google-22". How can I solve this kind of problem? I already installed some SDK components but it didn't work. Please give me some advice to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you seeing any errors? Are you using Android Studio or Eclipse? Windows or Mac?

Comment: What specifically didnt work? All that happens when you install SDK components is you download some files into a folder that you specified. Are the files there?

Comment: i'm using android studio on windows and the error was exactly like this during setup: "The following SDK components were not installed: sys-img-x86-addon-google_apis-google-22 and addon-google_apis-google-22".

Answer (score 1):

You did not give details about what exactly you installed and where the error comes from. But often people forget to follow this step after installing android sdk:

Run the SDK manager in your android-sdk folder and let it install the missing parts.